# Send a POST request containing encoded JSON

Tags: node.js, post

I am trying to make a POST call containing a JSON encoded form.

Why am i doing that ? I have no choice, i am working the the Facebook API which expects to receive a JSON encoded data and fire an error when receiving JSON.

I get the error `TypeError: stringify expects an object` when doing:

```
var datas = JSON.stringify({ some: "JSON" });
request.post('https://graph.facebook.com/...', { form: datas }, function(error,        response, body) {
    //Fail before the callback call
});
```

How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the `JSON.stringify` in the first line that fails here, it is the `form` property which is expected to be an object.

Don't try to send it as form data, just put the JSON text in the body of the request.

```
var datas = JSON.stringify({ some: "JSON" });
request.post('https://graph.facebook.com/...', { body: datas }, function(error,        response, body) {
  //Fail before the callback call
});
```